# Find out if a component is within a specific container

Tags: java, swing

I have an application with a lot of swing components, nested in several containers.
I'm implementing a right-click popup menu, showing information based upon the context the component is in.

To give an example:
If I right-click on a JTextField, I want to display "foo" in the popup if the textfield is within a JScrollPane, and "bar" if it is not. But the JTextField itself may be nested in several other JPanels.

i could do something like this:

```
public static boolean isInScrollPane(JComponent comp) {

    Container c = comp.getParent();

    while (c != null) {         
        if (c instanceof JScrollPane) {
            return true;
        } else {
            c = c.getParent();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But i bet there is a much better solution already available and I just didn't find it.

Could someone please give me a hint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code basically matches the [`SwingUtilies.getAncestorOfClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getAncestorOfClass%28java.lang.Class,%20java.awt.Component%29) method.  Your code can therefore be simplified to:

```
public static boolean isInScrollPane(JComponent comp)
{
  return SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JScrollPane.class, comp) != null;
}
```

Comment: ahh, i already thought it would be that simple. I looked through _SwingUtilities_ but didn't see this. thanks!